# Check if user is logged in using JQuery

Tags: jquery, login, jquery-ui

I want to execute custom jquery code which shows login dialog to user if he clicks a button and he is not logged in. How could I do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In case you want to know if the user is logged in at the current moment, try this. The other answers check if the user is logged in or not when the page loaded, not the time when you're running the javascript. The user could have logged in in a separate tab, for instance.

Put this in your javascript

```
var data = {
    action: 'is_user_logged_in'
};

jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    if(response == 'yes') {
        // user is logged in, do your stuff here
    } else {
        // user is not logged in, show login form here
    }
});
```

Put this in your `functions.php`

```
function ajax_check_user_logged_in() {
    echo is_user_logged_in()?'yes':'no';
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_is_user_logged_in', 'ajax_check_user_logged_in');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_is_user_logged_in', 'ajax_check_user_logged_in');
```

Comment: What is the value of ajaxurl?

Comment: wordpress sets it to 'yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'. That's the url on which all the ajax requests are supposed to be sent

Comment: I put the jQuery.post inside jquery click handler but this doesn't work. do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I saw that ajaxurl is not defined in the console.

Comment: [codex](codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) said that in latest wordpress versions this is already defined. Maybe you can define your own version of ajaxurl with wp_localize_script

Comment: The url should always point to "domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

Comment: Incase anyone get the ajaxurl is not defined... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710728/how-to-load-ajax-in-wordpress#17713643

Comment: @MridulAggarwal Thank you very much for this. Really thanks a lot.

Comment: where is functions.php?

Comment: `wp-content/themes/<current_theme>/functions.php`- make sure you check your current active theme from WordPress admin.

Answer (score 47):

Check the `class` attribute for `body`: If the theme is using `body_class()` the body has a class named `logged-in` for users that are logged in. Be aware the function can be used on the element `html` too.

Example with jQuery:

```
if(jQuery('body').hasClass('logged-in')){
    // Do something
}
```

Example with pure JavaScript:

```
if (document.body.classList.contains('logged-in')) {
    // do something
}
```

You can also just use `is_user_logged_in()` as a condition to enqueue or print the script.

Comment: top marks for this answer - simple and effective.

Comment: I like the idea of just checking the body for `logged-in` class. Just have to be sure that themes use `body_class();` or `get_body_class();` Otherwise, that's not a super reliable solution. Although, I use those functions in my themes, so that's a good solution for me. Thanks for the simple idea.

Answer (score 19):

Please add body_class() to your html body

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
   //your html code
</body>
```

This will add `logged-in` for logged user then you can use following jquery code to execute your custom juqery code only for logged user.

```
if ($('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
       //execute your jquery code.
}
```

Comment: I dunno why this one was down voted. Approach is fully valid. +1

Comment: I dont know. I have same question. Answer is valid but why down vote.

Comment: Hm. Maybe because it uses jQuery instead of the right way (using a filter and the callback). Some people are allergic to jQuery.

Comment: good, but it wouldnt tell actual login state if you use a cacheing plugin with page cache enabled.

Answer (score 8):

Please note that none of the above examples are reliable in case you use a page cacheing plugin, then the code in body tag will be static. Also there is a simple way to do this (with no extra query to ajax which is not optimal)

If you want to test user logged in state with javascript, you can use this code to set cookie when user logged in and delete cookie when user logged out. Add this eg. to your theme functions.php

```
function login_function() {
    setcookie('wp_user_logged_in', 1, time() + 31556926, '/');
    $_COOKIE['wp_user_logged_in'] = 1;
}
add_action('wp_login', 'login_function');

function logout_function() {
    unset($_COOKIE['wp_user_logged_in']);
    setcookie('wp_user_logged_in', null, -1, '/');
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'logout_function');
```

Then its a simple test of cookie in javascript.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('wp_user_logged_in') !== -1) {
    //do something when user logged in
} else {
    //do something when user logged out
}
```

Comment: This is indeed pretty simple, reliable and in worst case executes almost instantly after page load (if loading script in footer without render blocking) unlike other answers. Ajax is slow and relying on body classes will fail on caching. Need to add this cookie to Cookie Policy text. Thank You Janos.

Comment: As a follow-up, there is a problem with synchronization of default WordPress cookies and newly created script-accessible cookie, but I've received a great and simple answer on how to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208574/setting-script-accessible-cookie-expiry-based-on-wordpress-logged-in-cookie

Answer (score 6):

Another example, in case you want to use it for AJAX calls.

```
// Simplified... please note, that all names/vars/etc. in my class got unique names.
// ...the same goes for the script handler.
class wpse69814_example
{
    public $response;

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'localize' ), 20 );
    }

    public function enqueue()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'wpse69814_handler',
            plugins_url( 'url/to/file.js', __FILE__ ),
            array( 'jquery' ),
            filemtime( plugins_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'/path/to/file.js' ),
            true
        );
    }

    public function localize()
    {
        wp_localize_script( 'wpse69814_handler, 'wpse69814_object', array(
            'ajaxurl'    => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wpse69814_nonce' ),
            'action'     => 'wpse69814-handler-action',
            'data'       => array(
               'is_user_logged_in' => is_user_logged_in(),
            )
         )

    }
}
```

Comment: To note, this approach doesn't work behind CDN. :D

Comment: @BrianFegter Might want to explain (or [edit] it in) why? :)

Comment: Since the CDN doesn't authenticate with WordPress, `is_user_logged_in` will be cached as false in the DOM when origin is hit User state should be abstracted out to a no-cache thread via XHR when using a CDN. @Mridul Aggarwal's approach works but with no-cache headers in the response.

Comment: @BrianFegter Good catch. Fixed that... I think. Upvoted other answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this post and another post, I found a solution to my issue. I'm just posting in case anyone might find it useful.

***Works on current WordPress sites***

This code checks if user is logged or not using jquery. If the user is NOT logged in, it prevents the user from right clicking content and copying images and text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // if user is not logged in...
    if (!document.querySelector('body.logged-in')){
        //lock all content
        disableSelection(document.body);
        // disable image click
        $('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){return false;}); 
        console.log('hello');
    }

    // function to lock all content
    function disableSelection(target){
        $(function() {
             $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
             });
         }); 
         if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //For IE 
              target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
         else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //For Firefox
              target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
         else //All other route (For Opera)
              target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
         target.style.cursor = "default";
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using an alternative way **without** `ajaxurl` and `body class`. I just don't trust the body class, that might not exist in all of the themes.

In `functions.php` you should have:

```
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'custom_body_open' );

function custom_body_open() {
    $logged_in = is_user_logged_in() ? 'yes' : 'no'; //WP function to check if user is logged in or not
    echo '<div style="display:none" class="user_is_logged_in" data-logged-in="' . $logged_in . '" ></div>';
}
```

That creates an invisible `div` at the start of body tag with:

- class name "user_is_logged_in" - only for jQuery reference.
- style "display: none" - makes div invisible. Instead you can use CSS: `.user_is_logged_in { display: none }`
- "data-(logged-in)" value "yes" (logged in) or "no" (not logged in). That value will later be asked with `jQuery`.

In jQuery I ask the "data-logged-in" value and then act accordingly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var logged_in = $(".user_is_logged_in").data("logged-in") == 'yes' ? true : false;
    if (logged_in) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the WordPress script that will add class into the Body tag if the user is login or not login

https://gist.github.com/raftaar1191/55fe297db0724e62883846b3ed31b543

Answer (score -1):

I appreciated all the answers but localize script or checking the css class would be, in my opinion, not the best practice as the css class checking is not 100% reliable and the localize script function is, as the name suggests, localising.

After Wordpress 4.5 the best solution would be adding an inline script as follows:

```php
<?php

function detect_login() {
  $isLoggedIn = is_user_logged_in();
  wp_register_script( 'detect_login', '' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'detect_login');
  wp_add_inline_script( 'detect_login', "var isLoggedIn = $isLoggedIn" );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'detect_login' );
```

And then obviously check the global scope which is now sadly polluted by our global var isLoggedIn as follows: `window.isLoggedIn`

Comment: This is just what `wp_localize_script()` does.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes, the reason why they created `wp_add_inline_script()` is to avoid people using the localize script function to declare global variables. As the name suggests this is a better fit, why using something else which in the beginning wasn't intended for that purpose if we have a good alternative?

Comment: That's not what it was added for. It was added to support adding small bits of executable code before or after a script, to support things like font loaders. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/08/enhanced-script-loader-in-wordpress-4-5/

Comment: @JacobPeattie exactly, and what was `wp_localize_script()` string added for? Polluting the global scope with global variables? Or to actually localize as the name suggests?

Comment: What are you talking about? wp_localize_script forces you to namespace your variables inside an object. Your own answer is adding a variable to the global scope without any sort of namespace.

Comment: @JacobPeattie ehm, where do you think you will store the object from the `wp_localize_script()`? hint: `window`, anyways as you are so attached to `wp_localize_script()` feel free to keep your opinion about using it for declaring variables not related to localising instead of using the vanilla function made to do so, to each his own.