# How to save generated JWT token to cookies on login?

Tags: plugins, login, rest-api, cookies, authentication

I'm developing a Chrome extension and I want my users to authenticate via my WP login page.
I configured [JWT Authentication for WP Rest API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/).
I want the users to go to my website, login, and then have the generated JWT token save automatically in the client browser's cookies (or local storage) so I can grab it from my extension's script, and validate it when fetching requests.

Right now, when I login/logout and track my local storage and cookies, I don't see it being saved anywhere.
How can I do this?
Also, is this the right approach, or am I missing something?

Comment: I found this but it's not related to JWT: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/298840/203116